# addEventListener executing function multiple times on same input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm intending to build an autocomplete search box that searches through  **suggest_data** which approximately consists of 12,000+ data. The jquery takes value from search box, searches though the data array and stores the suggestion values in array which will be further used to populate the suggestion.

```
<input type="text" id="Search_box" placeholder="Search Data">

$('#Search_box').on('input', function () {
    suggester(document.getElementById("Search_box"));
});
```

The following function takes input value from search box and searches through search_array which has 12,000+ records and gives a list of data that have those characters in it as a suggestion.

```
function suggester(searchElement) {

var init;
searchElement.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var x, y, i, val = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { return false;}
        init = -1;

        var search_value = $('#Search_box').val();
        suggest_data = [];
        re = new RegExp("\\b\\w*" + search_value + "\\w*\\b", "ig");
        for (i = 0; i < search_array.length; i++) {
                if(search_array[i].match(re))
                         suggest_data = suggest_data.concat(search_array[i].match(re));
        }

        x = document.createElement("DIV");
        x.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        x.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        x.setAttribute("onClick", "this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(x);

        for (i = 0; i < suggest_data.length; i++) {
                y = document.createElement("DIV");
                val = truncate(suggest_data[i],30);
                reg = new RegExp(search_value, "ig");
                n = val.search(reg);
                res = suggest_data[i].substr(n,search_value.length);
                val = val.replace(res, '<span class="text_highlighter">'+res+'</span>');
                y.innerHTML = val;
                y.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + suggest_data[i]  + "'>";
                y.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        searchElement.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        closeAllLists();
                        $('#Search_box').focus();
                });
                x.appendChild(y);
                $('#Search_box').focus();
        }
});

searchElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            init++;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            init--;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (init > -1) {
                if (x) x[init].click();
            }
        }
});
function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (init >= x.length) init = 0;
    if (init < 0) init = (x.length - 1);
    x[init].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
}
function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
}
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != searchElement) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);

});
```

}

But this approach is slowing down when backspace is clicked. The addEventListener function is triggered multiple times hence it is looping inside the suggested function inorder to give result. Example if ASD is entered and if backspace is typed further on then it starts slowing down while giving result. What should be done inorder to speed up search?

Comment: Looks like you need a Debounce function - This is a good read for learning https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: _“The addEventListener function is triggered multiple times”_ - well of course it is, because you already added an input event handler on the element using jQuery syntax - and then inside that handler function, you are adding _another_ input handler by calling `addEventListener`, each and every time. That makes no sense to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every `keydown` your `eventListener` is triggering your `autocomplete` function. When someone clicks `backspace`, you're getting a heap of `keydown's` at the same time, and right now, that means you're running the function a number of times at the same time. This is what's slowing everything down.

> For example, if I were to type, "Hello my name is" and then delete the
> entire string, I'd have triggered your search 16 times, searching
> 12,000 x 16 records! You can start to see why this would become an issue.

A debounce function gets around this issue quite easily as it sets a delay between running again. Ie. if someone has just erased the entire string, it may just trigger once.

This is a great example of a debounce function:

```
    // http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) { func.apply(context, args); }
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) { func.apply(context, args); }
        };
    }
```

And this is how you would implement it on your code for autocomplete:

```
searchElement.addEventListener("keydown", debounce(function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            init++;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            init--;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (init > -1) {
                if (x) x[init].click();
            }
        }
}, 500)); // Time set here as callback for how often it should be run, change this to whatever you want the time delay to be.
```